# can't understand cmake find_package behaviour

Tags: c++, cmake

i'm using cmake find_package to find a package that is installed in two places, one on the system path (/usr/lib) and other on my custom path (/my/custom/path/lib). 
The one that i want to find is the one on custom path, for that I only desired to do the following:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/my/custom/path
```

but what i get with this command is the one installed on the system.

But if I copy the FindMyPackage.cmake script that is on the default cmake module path, to another folder and use it then the library that is found is the one in the custom path (the desired one), like this:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/my/custom/path -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=/path/to/copy/of/script
```

Can someone explain me why this is happening? and how can I instruct cmake to find only the custom one and not the system one without specifying a custom FindXXX.cmake script?

Note that i want to accomplish this without editing CMakeLists.txt, only with cmake flags, adding NO_* options on find_package() function is not the desired solution, because I want to use the system one or the custom one depending on external state and i don't want to edit cmake scripts for that.

Thanks
Nuno

---

**Update**

the script is FindProtobuf.cmake and it seems to me that is a version problem... newer versions use select_library_configurations and old ones don't, so my custom path is debug the system is release... and i think that on older versions the first that is used is the release one. On my module path i got the newest version that diferentiates debug from release and if my project is in debug then the right lib is selected... it seems a no issue :( but this is not easy to find or understand no...

Comment: Hard to say for sure without seeing the cmake module file. It's possible that you just need to clean out your build folder to remove the cached xxx_LIBRARIES and xxx_INCLUDE_DIRS variables.

Comment: it seems to strange... don't understand, and yes i always delete build folder when strange things happen :)
Don't know why they always try to find it in the system folder...

Comment: @JosephIreland is there any way to force cmake to look only to the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH paths specified in the command line?

Comment: Not directly. The FindXX.cmake file gets to choose where to look, you'll have to look in there.  Normally it uses stuff like [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) (make sure you read the docs for your version of cmake as there are differences). The search order would normally mean ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}/lib is checked first, then the system files. You can try to debug by looking at the cache variables with `cmake -LA -N`, or adding message() stuff in the module.

Comment: Without looking into `FindXXX.cmake` script which you use we can only **guess**, and guessing is not a way how Stack Overflow works. Please, show that script (or just say its name if is a standard CMake module).

Comment: you are right... the script is FindProtobuf.cmake and it seems to me that is a version problem... newer versions use select_library_configurations and old ones don't, so my custom path is debug the system is release... and i think that on older versions the first that is used is the release one. On my module path i got the newst version that diferentiates debug from release and if my project is in debug then the right lib is selected... it seems a no issue :( but this is not easy to find and understand no...